# Symfony Process component: argument substitution with curly braces

Tags: bash, symfony, substitution, curly-braces

Here is a code:

```
$cmd_make_sprite = '/usr/bin/gm convert /path/thumbs/video{1..353}.jpg -append /path/thumbs/sprite.jpg';

$process = new Process($cmd_make_sprite);
$process->run();
echo $process->getErrorOutput();
```

When I run this snippet I see this output:

> /usr/bin/gm convert: Unable to open file
>   (/path/thumbs/video{1..353}.jpg) [No such file or directory].

I think it happens because `video{1..353}.jpg` substitution doesn't work and Symfony Process builder treats this as a regular file name, which doesn't exist of course.

I tried to make a `sprite_wrapper.sh` for it:

```
#!/bin/bash

$@
```

and use it like this:

```
$cmd_make_sprite = 'bash sprite_wrapper.sh /usr/bin/gm convert /path/thumbs/video{1..353}.jpg -append /path/thumbs/sprite.jpg';

$process = new Process($cmd_make_sprite);
$process->run();
echo $process->getErrorOutput();
```

and it works, but I'd like to have a more clean code than that.

Does anyone have some thoughts how to improve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you perhaps have guessed, the `{x..y}` syntax only works in Bash.
But the default shell of `Process` is typically `/bin/sh`,
which may not be Bash. That's why your first attempt didn't work.

The intermediary `sprite_wrapper.sh` is really ugly,
and unnecessary. You can write like this:

```
$cmd_make_sprite = 'bash -c "/usr/bin/gm convert /path/thumbs/video{1..353}.jpg -append /path/thumbs/sprite.jpg"';
```

That is, you can pass Bash code to execute with `bash` using the `-c "..."` option.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thank you! Thank you for reminding this syntax with `bash -c`! Just curious, is it possible to change Symfony's shell to `bash` passing some property to its class?